# Problem creating an entity in the database using Entity Framework with existing child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, inner-classes

I am trying to insert an entity in the database using Entity Framework in C#. Here is the function that creates the venue in the database.

```
public async Task<Guid> CreateVenue(CurrentUser currentUser, CreateVenueDTO data, IAuthenticator authenticator)
{
    using (var db = contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();

        var venue = new Venue
            {
                Uid = uid,
                Name = data.Name,
                Address = data.Address,
                Description = data.Description,
                MaxCapacitySitting = data.MaxCapacitySitting,
                MaxCapacityStanding = data.MaxCapacityStanding,
                Lat = data.Lat,
                Lon = data.Lon
            };

        db.Venues.Add(venue);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        venue.VenueFacilities = new List<VenueFacility>();
        var venueFacilities = await db.Facilities.Where(x => data.FacilityUids.Contains(x.Uid)).ToListAsync();
        venueFacilities.ForEach(facility => venue.VenueFacilities.Add(new VenueFacility { Facility = facility, FacilityId = facility.Id, Venue = venue, VenueId = venue.Id, Rank = 0 }));

        db.Venues.Update(venue);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (data.Organization != null)
        {
            var orgUid = data.Organization.Uid;

            if (orgUid == Guid.Empty)
            {
                orgUid = await organizationService.CreateOrganization(currentUser, data.Organization);
            }

            venue.Organisation = db.Organizations.Where(x => x.Uid == orgUid).FirstOrDefault();
            db.Venues.Update(venue);

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
       }

       var venueTypes = await db.Types.Where(x => data.TypeUids.Contains(x.Uid)).ToListAsync();
       venue.VenueTypes = new List<VenueType>();

       venueTypes.ForEach(type => venue.VenueTypes.Add(new VenueType { VenueId = venue.Id, Venue = venue, TypeId = type.Id, Type = type }));

       db.Venues.Update(venue);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();

       venue.Pricing = new Pricing { Uid = Guid.NewGuid(), Package = data.Pricing.Package, MinimumHourCount = data.Pricing.MinimumHourCount ?? 0, MinimumPeopleCount = data.Pricing.MinimumPeopleCount ?? 0, WeekDays = data.Pricing.WeekDays ?? 0, WeekEnds = data.Pricing.WeekEnds ?? 0 };

       db.Venues.Update(venue);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();

       venue.VenueAvailabilityTimings = new List<AvailabilityTiming>();
            
       data.AvailabilityTimings.ToList().ForEach(availability => {
           DayTime from = null;
           DayTime to = null;
           WeekDay weekDay = db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == availability.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

           if (availability.From != null)
           {
               from = db.DayTimes.Where(f => f.Id == availability.From).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
               db.Detatch<DayTime>(from);
           }

           if (availability.To != null)
           {
               to = db.DayTimes.Where(t => t.Id == availability.To).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
               db.Detatch<DayTime>(to);
           }

           db.Detatch<WeekDay>(weekDay);

           var newAvailability = new AvailabilityTiming
                {
                    Uid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    From = from,
                    To = to,
                    DayOfWeek = weekDay,
                    AvailableAllDay = availability.AvailableAllDay
                };

           venue.VenueAvailabilityTimings.Add(newAvailability);                
       });

       db.Venues.Update(venue);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();

       venue.HowFarAdvanced = data.HowFarAdvanced;
       venue.VenueAvailabilityDates = new List<AvailabilityDate>();

       data.AvailabilityDates.ToList().ForEach(availability =>
            {
                Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar from = db.Calendars.Include(w => w.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().Where(f => f.Id == availability.From.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
                Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar to = db.Calendars.Include(w => w.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.Id == availability.To.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

                db.Detatch<Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar>(from);
                db.Detatch<WeekDay>(db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == from.DayOfWeek.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault());

                db.Detatch<Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar>(to);
                db.Detatch<WeekDay>(db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == to.DayOfWeek.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault());

                venue.VenueAvailabilityDates.Add(new AvailabilityDate 
                {
                    From = from,
                    To = to
                });
        });
            
        db.Venues.Update(venue);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            
        return uid;
    }
}
```

While inserting the availability dates at

```
 venue.VenueAvailabilityDates.Add(new AvailabilityDate 
                {
                    From = from,
                    To = to
                });
```

I get this error (even though I have detached possibly all the child entities)

> The instance of entity type 'WeekDay' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Here are the important classes

```
public class Calendar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DateColumn]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public WeekDay DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}

public class WeekDay
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
}

public class AvailabilityDate
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Calendar From { get; set; }
    public virtual Calendar To { get; set; }
}

public class AvailabilityTiming
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public WeekDay DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DayTime From { get; set; }
    public DayTime To { get; set; }
    public Boolean AvailableAllDay { get; set; }
}
```

It should be enough to detach the first immediate child to make this work. Since the data for Calendar and WeekDay already exist and I am only adding their relations (availability dates and week days). It is so difficult to do this task in Entity Framework.

Comment: Can you add your other class definitions? I don't see a class definition for `AvailabilityDate`, `AvailabilityTiming`, or your DbContext implementation (the class that defines what `db` is). I suspect there are some relationships between some of these classes and `WeekDay` that aren't obvious from the code you posted that cause issues with detaching entities.

Comment: I have added in the code above.

Comment: In the test case you are running, is the Id for the `WeekDay` object the same for both the `from` and `to` `Calendar` objects in this code:

        db.Detatch<Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar>(from);
        db.Detatch<WeekDay>(db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == from.DayOfWeek.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault());

        db.Detatch<Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar>(to);
        db.Detatch<WeekDay>(db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == to.DayOfWeek.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault());

Comment: Also, it looks like the error gave you a hint on enabling `DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging`. You can find details on how to use it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging?view=efcore-5.0. If you can find the Id for the offending `WeekDay` it will help you track it down.

Comment: Yes, the ids are the same that you asked for. Actually, I have saved the weekdays in the DB, similarly, I have saved the calendar dates for 30 years. I just refer to the Ids of the dates in the existing records when I have to create availability. The EntityFramework tries to add those weekdays and calendar dates again. There should be a possibility to ignore the addition of nested entities if they already exist.

Comment: The message is: The instance of entity type 'WeekDay' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 5}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I know the id is 5. But how to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226672/discussion-between-user810258-and-techfooninja).

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code since I don't have your database or your DbContext implementation, but I'll take a crack at it.

**The Problem**

The problem lies in this code:

```
data.AvailabilityDates.ToList().ForEach(availability =>
    {
        Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar from = db.Calendars.Include(w => w.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().Where(f => f.Id == availability.From.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar to = db.Calendars.Include(w => w.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.Id == availability.To.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

        db.Detatch<Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar>(from);
        db.Detatch<WeekDay>(db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == from.DayOfWeek.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault());

        db.Detatch<Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar>(to);
        db.Detatch<WeekDay>(db.WeekDays.Where(w => w.Id == to.DayOfWeek.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault());

        venue.VenueAvailabilityDates.Add(new AvailabilityDate 
        {
            From = from,
            To = to
        });
});
```

You detach the `Calendar` objects `from` and `to` from `db`. During that call, you also specifically include `DayOfWeek` (i.e. `Include(w => w.DayOfWeek)`) - this will hydrate a `DayOfWeek` object which your context now has knowledge of (even if you use `AsNoTracking()`). It looks like you also detach the `DayOfWeek` objects that match the child objects on `from` and `to`.

The problem is with this call:

```
venue.VenueAvailabilityDates.Add(new AvailabilityDate 
{
    From = from,
    To = to
});
```

You are creating a new `AvailabilityDate` and assigning detached `from` and `to` to it. Your context sees these detached objects as detached, and it assumes that you are trying to attach them. Within the `from` and `to` objects is your `DayOfWeek` child object - which is sounds like is identical for both `from` and `to` from your posted comment. Your context will then try to attach both of these child `DayOfWeek` objects, but will fail on the attaching the `WeekDay` object for `to` because a `WeekDay` object with **the same Id** was already attached to `from`. The context can't have two objects with identical Ids that it doesn't recognize as the same object - and it can't recognize them as the same object because they are detached.

**A Possible Solution**

Why worry about detaching at all? Entity Framework is smart enough to know that you're re-using an object without re-creating it. Just add that object, and allow your context to recognize that it already exists in the database and just need to be added as a property to your new object. This all assumes that you don't have some kind of unique index enforcing that `WeekDay` records can't be linked to multiple `Calendar` records, or that `Calendar` records can't be linked to multiple `AvailabilityDate` records.

```
data.AvailabilityDates.ToList().ForEach(availability =>
{
    Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar from = db.Calendars.Include(w => w.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().Where(f => f.Id == availability.From.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
    Scalable_Web_Data.Models.Calendar to = db.Calendars.Include(w => w.DayOfWeek).AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.Id == availability.To.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

    venue.VenueAvailabilityDates.Add(new AvailabilityDate 
    {
        From = from,
        To = to
    });
});
```

This should take an existing `from` and `to` (along with their already existing `DayOfWeek` objects), and create a new `AvailabilityDate` with the references to the existing objects you provided it.

If this creates new `Calendar` or `WeekDay` records, then you probably need to re-visit your `DbContext` implementation, specifically the relationships between objects and how the keys are used. I don't see that you specify any foreign keys on the objects you provided - I generally explicityly define them. For example:

```
public class AvailabilityDate
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FromId { get; set; }
    public int ToId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FromId))]
    public virtual Calendar From { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ToId))]
    public virtual Calendar To { get; set; }
}
```

This persists the Ids for `From` and `To` as fields in the database, and then uses those foreign keys to hydrate and populate the objects. Without specifying them, I'm not sure how EF would ever know that it could re-use objects.

Comment: ِI have already tried all this. The detach logic was the last try. But nothing worked. I had to change the design.